# Should the Roomba take bookmarks into account?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, bookmarks, automatic-deletion

About a month ago I asked a question on some technical aspect of C++, that went along these lines: "I read this and heard that, yet I have here what I believe to be a counter-example. What gives ?".

It received sort of an answer *as a comment* (the "I believe that [...]" kind), and was shortly bookmarked by myself and 2 other people. However, it received no upvote. About 3 weeks later, the question was downvoted once.

Earlier today, I had a discussion about the technical aspect that question was about. I wanted to link it and looked at my bookmarks to find it: the question was nowhere to be seen. It had just been a month since it was asked, had no accepted answer and had a score of -1, so [the Roomba took care of it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba).

I find it odd that the Roomba would delete a question bookmarked by someone else than the author. Perhaps it wasn't good, but it seems that two unrelated people deemed it useful enough that they made it so they could easily return to it later.

They won't be able to.

One could argue that it they wanted to return to it, they should've upvoted it, but then an argument can also be made that upvoting and bookmarking mean different things, and that not everyone knows about Roomba rules.

Currently, no matter how many times a question is bookmarked, the Roomba doesn't care and may delete it and its related information. I could see the fact you don't need any reputation to bookmark questions as a possible cause, but I imagine that's not exceedingly hard to work around ("bookmarked by users with >n rep...").

Should the Roomba take bookmarks into account, and if not, what are the reasons ?

Comment: Somewhat: I now see that bookmarking doesn't necessarily mean the person found it useful, but I'd assume it still means that most of the time and people are just selfish and can't be bothered to upvote. If I had a utility estimate on how much does it "cost to the users" to have a questions 'wrongly' kept open, and 'wrongly' closed, and how often does that happen, there could be a more interesting discussion, but I don't.
But yeah, I didn't consider not all bookmarks meant someone wants it not to be closed. I think some do though. So, I still wonder what's the best solution on average there.

Comment: Bookmarking only means that you don't want to lose a link to it. It doesn't mean that the question is good or bad

Comment: God, I hope that bookmarks are never taken into account as they are no reflection of question quality whatsoever.

Comment: I've bookmarked loads of stuff so that I could go back and see if the writer's fixed it yet.

Comment: The bookmarks were *specifically* renamed ***to*** "Bookmarks" to disassociate them with positive or negative. They used to be called "Favourites" but never really acted as that. The feature allows users to save certain questions it is *not* meant to be "this question is good". I might bookmark a question to act on it later, like cast a deletion vote. I might bookmark it to read it later and thus can't vote or it right now. I might bookmark it after I've determined that I don't want to vote up or down for whatever reason but I might still want a link to it.

Comment: "*it seems that two unrelated people deemed it useful enough that they made it so they could easily return to it later. They won't be able to.*" bookmarks to deleted questions are retained. Users with [the 10k reputation privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) can see deleted content.

Comment: Relevant: [Favorites are now known as Bookmarks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347558) and [How do question bookmarks work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53585)

Answer (score 21):

> an argument can also be made that upvoting and bookmarking mean different things

Yes they do mean different things: upvoting means you think a question has value and should be kept on the site; and bookmarking does not mean that, so it shouldn't be interpreted as that.

They might have bookmarked it because it is so bad they want to make sure it gets deleted.

Comment: Is that not what the "Follow" functionality is for? Not to imply that I think bookmarks should necessarily equate to upvotes.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest Yes, following can be used the same way. That also should not influence the roomba not to delete something.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Just because that is how you use bookmarks does not mean that is what everyone uses them for.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Did you understand the last sentence of my answer?